# Как изменить размер ImageView с помощью жестов?

Tags: android, imageview, touch, multi-touch

Каким образом можно изменить размер изображения с помощью жеста двумя пальцами в пределах компонента? С изменением размера всё ясно, каким образом отслеживать 2 касания? Как я понимаю это мультитач?

Comment: Называется Pinch zoom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630373/android-image-view-pinch-zooming

Comment: Дополнительно можно посмотреть тут: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/168-urok-103-multitouch-obrabotka-mnozhestvennyh-kasanij.html